# Consider the polynomial equation $x^{5}-x-1=0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, polynomials, cauchy-sequences

Consider the polynomial equation $x^{5}-x-1=0$

(a) Show that this equation has a solution x = r with $1 <r <2$

(b) Define an appropriate contractive sequence $X_{n}$ and approximate r with an accuracy of $10^{-4}$

I thought about rewriting the equation as $x=x^{5}-1$ but it didn't work because the succession that resulted was not contractive. How can I solve the problem? I think we can use the mean value theorem of differential functions, if they could help me it would be good. Thank you

Comment: For (a), an application of the intermediate value theorem gets the job done.  I'm not sure exactly what you are looking for for (b) as I don't know what theory you are working from, but it seems that Newton's method approximation should get the job done.

Comment: If you don't like Newton's method, $x=(x+1)^{1/5}$ will work, as this maps $[1,2]$ into itself and is contractive on $[1,2]$. (Usually this is the way to go for "algebraically" constructing a contraction from a polynomial equation, unless one of the non-leading coefficients of the equation is rather large.) Newton's method will converge faster, though, especially since the function is increasing and convex on $(5^{-1/5},\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hints:*

(a) Use the intermediate value theorem.

(b) Use Newton's method with $x_0\ge2$.